# Extracting Patterns using Neural Networks

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, pattern-recognition

I am trying to extract common patterns that always appear whenever a certain event occurs.

For example, patient A, B, and C all had a heart attack. Using the readings from there pulse, I want to find the common patterns before the heart attack stroke.

In the next stage I want to do this using multiple dimensions. For example, using the readings from the patients pulse, temperature, and blood pressure, what are the common patterns that occurred in the three dimensions taking into consideration the time and order between each dimension.

What is the best way to solve this problem using Neural Networks and which type of network is best?
(Just need some pointing in the right direction)

and thank you all for reading

Comment: I'd encourage using a library such as Tensorflow or Theano in Python for the development of your classifier. Google published [a great introduction to Tensorflow on Udacity](https://www.udacity.com/course/deep-learning--ud730), look it up.

Comment: Thanks @pzelasko I already downloaded TensorFlow, however I need help with figuring out the architecture

Comment: If you're dealing with temporal data then you might want to try out Recurrent Neural Networks, in particular LSTMs (they're explained in the course). Just keep in mind that you'll probably need a lot of data. If its not temporal then you could just use a feed-forward net and experiment with number of layers, neurons, activations, etc.

Comment: Thanks again @pzelasko, so you don't suppose I need to try out convolutional networks, or RBM's perhaps? 
The link you sent is very good I will definitely take that course! 
The data will be at rest when building the patterns, and then they will be real time when using the pattern to predict the event.

Comment: Of course you could try out convolutionals (or other architectures as well). You won't know what works best until you try it. As for the RBMs AFAIK they're used more in an unsupervised manner as autoencoders/features extractors or as a means of pre-training a classifier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Described problem looks like a time series prediction problem. That means a basic prediction problem for a continuous or discrete **phenomena** generated by some existing **process**. As a **raw data** for this problem we will have a sequence of **samples** x(t), x(t+1), x(t+2), ..., where x() means an output of considered process and t means some arbitrary timepoint.

For artificial neural networks solution we will consider a time series prediction, where we will **organize** our raw data to a new sequences. As you should know, we consider X as a matrix of input vectors that will be used in ANN learning. For time series prediction we will construct a new collection on following schema.

In the most basic form your input vector x will be a sequence of samples (x(t-k), x(t-k+1), ..., x(t-1), x(t)) taken at some arbitrary timepoint t, appended to it predecessor samples from timepoints t-k, t-k+1, ..., t-1. You should generate every example for every possible timepoint t like this.

But the key is to **preprocess** data so that we get the best prediction results.

Assuming your data (phenomena) is continuous, you should consider to apply some **sampling** technique. You could start with an experiment for some naive sampling period Δt, but there are stronger methods. See for example [Nyquist–Shannon Sampling Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist%E2%80%93Shannon_sampling_theorem), where the key idea is to allow to recover continuous x(t) from discrete x(Δt) samples. This is reasonable when we consider that we probably expect our ANNs to do this.

Assuming your data is discrete... you still should need to try sampling, as this will speed up your computations and might possibly provide better generalization. But the key advice is: **do experiments!** as the best architecture depends on data and also will require to preprocess them correctly.

The next thing is network output layer. From your question, it appears that this will be a binary class prediction. But maybe a wider prediction vector is worth considering? How about to **predict the future** of considered samples, that is x(t+1), x(t+2) and experiment with different **horizons** (length of the future)?

Further reading:

1. Somebody mentioned Python here. Here is some good tutorial on timeseries prediction with Keras: [Victor Schmidt, Keras recurrent tutorial, Deep Learning Tutorials](https://github.com/Vict0rSch/deep_learning/tree/master/keras/recurrent)
2. This paper is good if you need some real example: [Fessant, Francoise, Samy Bengio, and Daniel Collobert. "On the prediction of solar activity using different neural network models." Annales Geophysicae. Vol. 14. No. 1. 1996.](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.23.3545&rep=rep1&type=pdf)

Comment: Thank you for your well explained answer

Comment: I hope this will point you to some reasonable direction where preprocessing of data matters. After determining the data shape (not to be confused with `numpy.shape` from Python Numpy library), proper definition of your problem should help you with model (network) selection.

Comment: This is what had me confused. From what I read so far about Neural Networks, I understand that I don't need to extract shaplets, the network itself will determine the class of the current event through its calculations.

Comment: Yes, artificial neural network will determine the class but remember that the process of learning is based on showing examples labeled with these classes (or "labeled" with other data, like time series future). Network itself will determine different connections, like feature importance, but these things have different meaning for different shape of data.

Comment: When you say shape of data you mean label correct? Since I assumed you meant pattern of data that is repeating itself in each class. That is what I wanted to use to detect if a new time series is in a certain class.

Comment: @Haz, mostly yes. Essentially, both input and output (label) layer shapes are important here. But, regarding your current question, assuming your input layer is meaningful, you are about to detect different patterns for different shape of output layer. Consider binary output (1 - heart attack present, 0 - opposite) and an input of time series window. Intuition says that using a Perceptron here wont be effective, as we want to recognize "patterns" of different relations between subsequent timepoints. This is not possible without a hidden layer.

Comment: For "predicting the future" chances are improved, as every timepoint t probably affects timepoint t+1, t+10 etc. In other words, different shape means different problem and different possible solutions for it - from model selection to learned model interpretation. I hope this highlights the reasons of when and why deep and convolutional networks are needed.

Comment: Would you recommend convolutional networks over recurrent networks for such a problem?

Comment: I don't have such experience in the former but I've seen more successfull applications with recurrent networks. You should also consider LSTM, like suggested by @pzelasko. Hint: for the second one, your input vector shouldn't be that long as considered in my posts, but that, like everythin else, depends on data .

Comment: Thank you, you have been very helpful!